# Displaying jquery alerts with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I'm new to PHP and everything is very confusing to me. What I'm trying to do and fail is to display an alert on the screen on click of a button on the page.

my Code signInFunction.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['signIn'])){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
        <?php
        echo "username is: ".$username." and password is: ". $password;
    }
    else{
        echo "Please enter username and password";
    }
}
else{
    echo "error button";
}
?>
```

in the index.php file looks like this:

```
  <?php include "includes/header.php" ?>
  <?php include "includes/navbar.php" ?>
  <?php include "includes/carousel.php"?> 
  <?php include "includes/marketing.php"?> 
  <?php include "includes/features.php"?>
  <?php include "includes/hidden.php"?>
  <?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
  <?php include "includes/functions/signinFunction.php"?>
```

The Problem is that I manage to display the data at the bottom but fail to make the alert appear.. what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echoing a jquery alert popup in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532338/echoing-a-jquery-alert-popup-in-php)

Comment: @swidmann OP is using one of the methods described in the question. not a duplicate imho.

Comment: Did you check page source? Do you see your alert function? Is browser reporting you some JS error or something?

Comment: @user3456351 according to your script, the `<script>` tag can only end up in the document if you are `POST`ing, and setting `signIn` in your POST variables. are you actually doing this? (is the script tag visible if you view the source of your output?)

Comment: @TimothyGroote, well maybe you're right, but I thought the basic problem is still the same.

Comment: The browser does not report any JS error or something. when I open signInfunction.php and inspect elements I have header body and inside Connected Succesfullyerror button text

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" method="post" >
   <input name='username' type='text' value=''/>
   <input name='password' type='text' value='' />
   <input type='button' name='signIn' value='Sign In' />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['signIn'])){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
        <?php
        echo "username is: ".$username." and password is: ". $password;
    }
    else{
        echo "Please enter username and password";
    }
}
else{
    echo "error button";
}
?>
```

when u click on the sign in button then that alert should appear

Comment: well yes this works, but why does not it work with the approach I had above?

Comment: because you didn`t submitted any form I think, Take a look on this :) http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("alert")';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: you can simple use above code to execute alert within php snippet.